# How to drop an external table in Kusto ONLY IF IT EXISTS

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

How to drop an external table without know if it exists or not? Basically we have optional `ifexists` clause for a normal table but not for an external table. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to Microsoft doc - [External table general control commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/external-table-commands#drop-external-table)

```
.drop external table tableName
```

[image: Here is an extract from microsoft doc]

Answer (score 2):

i'd recommend voting for missing features/functionality you'd like to see implemented at the service's User Voice forum (https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice).

a 'workaround' for the time being is performing the operation in two steps - run a `.show` command to see if the external table exists, and if it does - run a `.drop` command

(*update:* you can expect the `ifexists` option to become available within the next 2 weeks)